# GUI Quiz using easygui and pygame issue with quieting the game and playing sound .mp3

Tags: pygame, easygui

Can any one help with exiting the game and my .mp3 files not playing just making a buzz noise for example every time you answer right or wrong instead of the actual sound?

Is it possible to get the quiz to exit by hitting the cross button on window as at the moment it does not let you exit until you answered all 10 questions?

```
#We start by importing a few libraries.
    #Easygui provides our GUI for the game.
    from easygui import *
    #Time is a library that introduces the concept of time to the game.
    import time
    #Pygame is a series of multimedia tools that can create games using Python.
    import pygame

    #To start pygame we need to initialise it.
    pygame.init()
    #To use the audio facilities of Pygame we need to tell Pygame that we wish to use them.
    pygame.mixer.init()

    #Now we create three functions, these functions contain the code to play each audio track.
    #The audio for each of these functions should be in the same folder as this code.
    def intro():
        intro = pygame.mixer.Sound('audio/intro.mp3')
        intro.play(1)

    def win():
        win = pygame.mixer.Sound('audio/correct.mp3')
        win.play(1)

    def lose():
        lose = pygame.mixer.Sound('audio/wrong.mp3')
        lose.play(1)

    #To keep our score, we create a variable called score and set it to zero.
    score = 0
    #The next variable contains the location of the KS2 geography project logo.
    logo = "./images/globe.jpg"
    #This is a list, sometimes called an array. In here I store two items.
    play = ["Yes","No"]

    #I start the game by calling the intro() function, and this plays the quiz theme.
    intro()
    #Here we create a variable called game_start and it will store the answer to the question "Would you like to play the quiz?"
    #To capture the answer I use the buttonbox function from easygui. This function has many options, for this I use.
    #title = The text at the top of the dialog box.
    #image = logo, the variable I earlier created.
    #msg = This is the question that I ask the player.
    #choices = play. I use this to reference the earlier created list and use the values contained as the choices for the player.
    start_title = "Welcome to KS2 Geography Game Quiz"
    start_msg = "Would you like to play the Quiz?"
    game_start = buttonbox(title=start_title,image=logo,msg=start_msg,choices=play)

    #For debugging purposes I have the answer given by the player printed to the Python shell.
    print(game_start)#Here we see some conditional logic that tests to see if the answer was "Yes" If the answer is not equal to No, it proceeds.
    if game_start != "No":
        #Here is another easygui dialog box, a message box. It has the same syntax as the previous box we created.
        #You can see str(score) in the line below. In order to join a string of text, our message, with the value
        #of the score we need to wrap the score, which is an integer, in a helper function that converts integers
        #and floats into strings
        msgbox(title="Let us begin",msg="Your score is "+str(score))

        count = 0
        #Question 1
        for i in range(0,4):
            msg = "Where is capital of the Netherlands?"
            hint1 = "It's not Tehran"
            hint2 = "It's not London"
            title = "Question 1"
            q1choices = ["Tehran","London","Amsterdam","Abu Dhabi"]
            if count==0:           
                q1 = choicebox(msg,title,q1choices)
            elif count ==1:
                msg += hint1
                q1 = choicebox(msg,title,q1choices)
            else:
                msg += hint2
                q1 = choicebox(msg,title,q1choices)

            if q1 == "Amsterdam":
                win()
                if count == 0:
                    score += 1
                elif count ==1:
                    score +=0.8
                else:
                    score +=0.6
                correct = ("Well done you got it right. Your score is "+str(score))
                image = "./images/tick.gif"
                msgbox(title="CORRECT",image=image,msg=correct)
                count = 0
                break
            else:
                lose()
                wrong = "I'm sorry that's the wrong answer"
                image = "./images/cross.gif"
                msgbox(title="Wrong Answer",image=image,msg=wrong)
                count +=1

        #Question 2
        for i in range(0,4):
            msg = "Which Continent is Britian part of?"
            hint1 = "       You should know this one!"
            hint2 = "       It is the smallest of them all..."
            title = "Question 2"
            q2choices = ["Europe","America", "Asia","Africa"]

            if count == 0:
                q2 = choicebox(msg,title,q2choices)
            elif count ==1:
                msg += hint1
                q2 = choicebox(msg,title,q2choices)
            else:
                msg += hint2
                q2 = choicebox(msg,title,q2choices)

            if q2 == "Europe":
                win()
                if count ==0:
                    score += 1
                elif count ==1:
                    score += 0.8
                else:
                    score += 0.6

                correct = ("Well done you got it right. Your score is "+str(score))
                image = "./images/tick.gif"
                msgbox(title="CORRECT",image=image,msg=correct)
                count =0
                break
            else:
                lose()
                wrong = "I'm sorry that's the wrong answer"
                image = "./images/cross.gif"
                msgbox(title="Wrong Answer",image=image,msg=wrong)
                count += 1


        #Question 3
        for i in range(0,4):
            msg = "Which of these countries are not in European Union?"
            hint1 = "       located next to Greece!"
            hint2 = "       Capital city of this country called Tirana!"
            title = "Question 3"
            q3choices = ["Latvia","Albania","Estonia","France"]
            if count == 0:
                q3 = choicebox(msg,title,q3choices)
            elif count ==1:
                msg += hint1
                q3 = choicebox(msg,title,q3choices)
            else:
                msg += hint2
                q3 = choicebox(msg,title,q3choices)

            if q3 == "Albania":
                win()
                if count ==0:
                    score += 1
                elif count ==1:
                    score += 0.8
                else:
                    score += 0.6

                correct = ("Well done you got Albania! hard wasnt it? Your score is "+str(score))
                image = "./images/tick.gif"
                msgbox(title="CORRECT",image=image,msg=correct)
                count = 0
                break
            else:
                lose()
                wrong = "I'm sorry that's the wrong answer only 3rd Question!"
                image = "./images/cross.gif"
                msgbox(title="Wrong Answer",image=image,msg=wrong)
                count += 1


        #Question 4
        for i in range(0,4):
            msg = "How many continents are in the world?"
            hint1 = "       count all of them! "
            hint2 = "       Really? "
            title = "Question 4"
            q4choices = ["7","3","5","4"]

            if count == 0:
                q4 = choicebox(msg,title,q4choices)
            elif count ==1:
                msg += hint1
                q4 = choicebox(msg,title,q4choices)
            else:
                msg += hint2
                q4 = choicebox(msg,title,q4choices)

            if q4 == "7":
                win()
                if count ==0:
                    score +=1
                elif count ==1:
                    score += 0.8
                else:
                    score += 0.6

                correct = ("Was easy right? Your score is "+str(score))
                image = "./images/tick.gif"
                msgbox(title="CORRECT",image=image,msg=correct)
                count =0
                break
            else:
                lose()
                wrong = "nice try! Think again and dont forget to add them all up..."
                image = "./images/cross.gif"
                msgbox(title="Wrong Answer",image=image,msg=wrong)
                count+=1

        #Question 5
        for i in range(0,4):
            msg = "Where is the largest country in Europe?"
            hint1 = "       It is outside EU!"
            hint2 = "       It is also the Largest country in the world!"
            title = "Question 5"
            q5choices = ["France","Germany","Russia","UK"]

            if count ==0:
                q5 = choicebox(msg,title,q5choices)
            elif count ==1:
                msg+=hint1
                q5 = choicebox(msg,title,q5choices)
            else:
                msg+=hint2
                q5 = choicebox(msg,title,q5choices)

            if q5 == "Russia":
                win()
                if count==0: 
                    score += 1
                elif count ==1:
                    score+=0.8
                else:
                    score+=0.6

                correct = ("Well done you got it right. Your score is "+str(score))
                image = "./images/tick.gif"
                msgbox(title="CORRECT",image=image,msg=correct)
                count=0
                break
            else:
                lose()
                wrong = "I'm sorry that's the wrong answer"
                image = "./images/cross.gif"
                msgbox(title="Wrong Answer",image=image,msg=wrong)
                count+=1

        #Question 6
        for i in range(0,4):
            msg = "What is a book of maps called?"
            hint1 = "       I Think you pressed the wrong choice by mistake!"
            hint2 = "       Really?"
            title = "Question 6"
            q6choices = ["Dictionary","Book","Atlas","Atlantic"]

            if count ==0:
                q6 = choicebox(msg,title,q6choices)
            elif count ==1:
                msg+=hint1
                q6 = choicebox(msg,title,q6choices)
            else:
                msg+=hint2
                q6 = choicebox(msg,title,q6choices)

            if q6 == "Atlas":
                win()
                if count ==0:
                    score += 1
                elif count ==1:
                    score += 0.8
                else:
                    score += 0.6

                correct = ("Din not need to think about it right? Your score is "+str(score))
                image = "./images/tick.gif"
                msgbox(title="CORRECT",image=image,msg=correct)
                count=0
                break
            else:
                lose()
                wrong = "I'm sorry that's the wrong answer! but keep thinking"
                image = "./images/cross.gif"
                msgbox(title="Wrong Answer",image=image,msg=wrong)
                count+=1

            #Question 7
        for i in range(0,4):
            msg = "Which is the largest desert in the world?"
            hint1 = "       The area of this desert is 9 400 000 SQ KM"
            hint2 = "       it is located in Africa"
            title = "Question 7"
            q7choices = ["Malavi","Sahara","Gobi","Arabia"]

            if count == 0:
                q7 = choicebox(msg,title,q7choices)
            elif count ==1:
                msg+= hint1
                q7 = choicebox(msg,title,q7choices)
            else:
                msg+=hint2
                q7 = choicebox(msg,title,q7choices)

            if q7 == "Sahara":
                win()
                if count ==0:
                    score += 1
                elif count ==1:
                    score += 0.8
                else:
                    score += 0.6

                correct = ("GOOD job mate! hard ones are comimg... Your score is "+str(score))
                image = "./images/tick.gif"
                msgbox(title="CORRECT",image=image,msg=correct)
                count=0
                break
            else:
                lose()
                wrong = "I'm sorry that's the wrong answer"
                image = "./images/cross.gif"
                msgbox(title="Wrong Answer",image=image,msg=wrong)
                count+=1

            #Question 8
        for i in range(0,4):
            msg = "Which is the highest mountain in Britain?"
            hint1 = "       i did not know it myslef so cant help :)"
            hint2 = "       It is located in Scotland somewhere!"
            title = "Question 8"
            q8choices = ["Everest","Mont Blanc","Ben Nevis","Ben Mac"]

            if count==0:
                q8 = choicebox(msg,title,q8choices)
            elif count ==1:
                msg+=hint1
                q8 = choicebox(msg,title,q8choices)
            else:
                msg+=hint2
                q8 = choicebox(msg,title,q8choices)

            if q8 == "Ben Nevis":
                win()
                if count ==0:
                    score += 1
                elif count ==1:
                    score += 0.8
                else:
                    score += 0.6

                correct = ("Well done you got it right. Your score is "+str(score))
                image = "./images/tick.gif"
                msgbox(title="CORRECT",image=image,msg=correct)
                count=0
                break
            else:
                lose()
                wrong = "I'm sorry that's the wrong answer"
                image = "./images/cross.gif"
                msgbox(title="Wrong Answer",image=image,msg=wrong)
                count += 1

            #Question 9
        for i in range(0,4):
            msg = "When do you see rainbow?"
            hint1 = "       water must be available in air to form a rainbow!"
            hint2 = "       vright light in air plus water will cause this beautiful phenonema!"
            title = "Question 9"
            q9choices = ["When Rainy & Sunny","When Windy & Sunny","When Cloudy & Rainy","When Foggy & Rainy"]

            if count ==0:
                q9 = choicebox(msg,title,q9choices)
            elif count ==1:
                msg+=hint1
                q9 = choicebox(msg,title,q9choices)
            else:
                msg+=hint2
                q9 = choicebox(msg,title,q9choices)

            if q9 == "When Rainy & Sunny":
                win()
                if count ==0:
                    score += 1
                elif count ==1:
                    score += 0.8
                else:
                    score += 0.6

                correct = ("Well done you got it right again... Your score is "+str(score))
                image = "./images/tick.gif"
                msgbox(title="CORRECT",image=image,msg=correct)
                count =0
                break
            else:
                lose()
                wrong = "I'm sorry that's the wrong answer"
                image = "./images/cross.gif"
                msgbox(title="Wrong Answer",image=image,msg=wrong)
                count+=1

            #Question 10
        for i in range(0,4):
            msg = "Which is not a precipitation?"
            hint1 = "       Google it!"
            hint2 = "       it doesnt come from sky!"
            title = "Question 10"
            q10choices = ["Rain","Snow","Hail","Frost"]

            if count ==0:
                q10 = choicebox(msg,title,q10choices)
            elif count ==1:
                msg+=hint1
            else:
                msg+=hint2
                q10 = choicebox(msg,title,q10choices)
            if q10 == "Frost":
                win()
                if count ==0:
                    score += 1
                elif count ==1:
                    score += 0.8
                else:
                    score += 0.6
                score += 1
                correct = ("Well done you got it right. Your score is "+str(score))
                image = "./images/tick.gif"
                msgbox(title="CORRECT",image=image,msg=correct)
                count =0
                break
            else:
                lose()
                wrong = "I'm sorry that's the wrong answer your score is lowering"
                image = "./images/cross.gif"
                msgbox(title="Wrong Answer",image=image,msg=wrong)
                count+=1



        gameover_good = "./images/well_done.gif"
        gameover_bad = "./images/trymore.jpg"
        intro()
        game_over_title = "KS2 Geography Quiz"
        msg_bad = ("Oh dear you scored "+str(score))
        msg_good = ("Well done you scored "+str(score))
        if score < 5:
            game_over = msgbox(title = game_over_title,image = gameover_bad,msg = msg_bad)
        else:
            game_over = msgbox(title = game_over_title,image = gameover_good,msg = msg_good)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Stopping early:**

In older versions of easygui the 'X' isn't supported.

Are you willing to work with a development branch of easygui?  if so, take a look here:  https://github.com/robertlugg/easygui/tree/develop
.  Eventually, it will get released but that will be a bit yet.

Recently both the 'X' and 'Cancel' will return a value of None.  So, in your code, you might add lines like:

```
    if q1 is None:
        print("ok, end of game")
        exit()
```

Again, you have to use a fairly new version in 'develop'.  If you don't want to do that, you may also see what is returned when 'Cancel' is pressed even in the older versions.  It may return an empty string or None which you could test against.

**Bad sound:**

I was able to replicate your problem.  I'm no expert on pygame, but refer to this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18818520

I converted the .mp3 to .ogg and changed the filename at that did it!

Good luck and keep up the good work!